# Facebook doesn't scrape pictures from my blog's posts URLs

Tags: facebook, image, url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have a blog and a fan page on Facebook for that same blog. Daily, I publish my blog posts on the Facebook Fan Page manually. Until a week ago all I had to do was paste the URL of the post and facebook scraper extracted all the images related to the post, along with metadata and post excerpts. I chose the picture I liked and publish the post.

But a week ago when I type a URL Facebook always draws the same pictures, as if he couldn't detect images within URLs. How I can fix this? Any idea?

My blog is http://applediario.com and my fan page is https://www.facebook.com/applediario.

Comment: Sometimes, all you have to do is run your URL though the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fapplediario.com%2F) to refresh the cache. Right now it's complaining that you specified an `oh:image` tag but gave no value.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the og:image tag in your Open Graph meta tags.

Read here:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/facebook-open-graph-wordpress/